# PHP and MySQL deleting fields in database when it shouldn't

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm using a simple HTML form with a 2 submit buttons. Each button enacts a PHP function that inserts data into a specific field in my database. The PHP function that the first submit button enacts contains this mysql code:

```
    $placeA = "".$_SESSION['username']."";
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("Couldn't connect!");
    mysql_select_db("login") or die("Couldn't find db");

    $queryreg = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO places VALUES ('$placeA', '$placeB')
    ");
```

and the second button enacts a very similar PHP function that contains this mysql code:

```
    $placeB = "".$_SESSION['username']."";
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("Couldn't connect!");
    mysql_select_db("login") or die("Couldn't find db");

    $queryreg = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO places VALUES ('$placeA', '$placeB')
    ");
```

When I push the first button it does what it's supposed to do. It assigns $placeA as the username, and then it adds $placeA to the first column of the "places" table in the database. My problem comes when I then click the second button. This second function inserts the username into the database under the second column of the "places" table like it's supposed to, but it ALSO DELETES the username that was already inserted into the first column. If I then click the first button again, it inserts the username into the first column AND DELETES the username from the second column. It's as if they are mutually exclusive for some reason? What should I do? (None of the other code is relevant to the database at all. It's just a bunch of echos.)

Comment: I think you might have a substantial misunderstanding of the concept of a database table. The INSERT statement INSERTS a new row into the table places. I assume that the variable `$placeA` is not set in your second script - therefore it will add a row with a empty first column.

Comment: Can you post the definition of the login.places table?

Comment: Aside from that, using the root account to access your database is very bad if you're on a production machine. Not to also mention the SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

The $placeA and $placeB variables are defined using session , if you don't define every time each var you will have back and empty one , if you structture accepts NULL in the fields ( placeA or placeB ) the result will be a strange strange record .

IMHO , start to use more extend query "INSERT INTO (field1, field2, ..) values ('val1',val2,etc) . it will be more clear for debug .